# Error opening/initializing the selected video_out (-vo) device

Tags: raspberry-pi, adafruit

I have an `Adafruit 2.2" PiTFT HAT - 320x240 Display` connected to a RaspberryPi and when I try to play a video with this command:

```
sudo SDL_VIDEODRIVER=fbcon SDL_FBDEV=/dev/fb1 mplayer -vo sdl -framedrop bigbuckbunny320p.mp4
```

I am getting this error:

```
[VO_SDL] SDL initialization failed: Unable to open /dev/fb1.
Error opening/initializing the selected video_out (-vo) device.
```

tutorial: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-2-2-pitft-hat-320-240-primary-display-for-raspberry-pi/playing-videos